# How can I create Xcode docsets that look and work like the ones in Apple Core Library

Tags: xcode, doxygen

I want to create a docset for my API that looks and works like the Apple Core Library docset. For example, look at the page for NSString.

I've tried Doxygen and I've tried headerdoc2html. Neither does very close to what I want.

The files generated by headerdoc don't have most of the higher-level structure that the Apple files do, and the graphics design is different. Down at the more detailed level, like when looking at a specific method, things are closer, but don't have all the detailed structure.

The files generated by Doxygen have a very different high-level structure, not to mention having a very different graphic design.

What else should I try? Or are there parameters to either of these tools that would give me something closer?

Thanks, Pat

Answer (score 10):

The best I have found so far is  [Tomaz's appledoc](http://github.com/tomaz/appledoc). With it I can create apple style api documentation and instal it directly into the DocSets that Xcode is uisng. Works very well and is based on doxygen.

Comment: Hi Derek,
   I should have responded earlier. I did that project by hand-editing the HTML back in August. (Ugh! Massive Ugh! But it worked.) When I need to update it, I'll look at Tomaz's stuff. I don't want to accept an answer until I've tried it, but I'll revisit this when I have.
Thanks,
Pat

Comment: There's a good rendition example (with appledoc) here : http://www.gentlebytes.com/content/appledoc/exampledoc/
 (nice ! at least nicer than the basic doxygen rendition ;)

Comment: Yes, appleDoc keeps on getting better and better. No I didn't write it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Doxygen to generate Xcode docsets](http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html).

Comment: The question was how to generate Xcode docsets that look like the ones that Apple delivers for their APIs. If Doxygen can do this, I haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: oh, well in that case can't you just use a custom CSS which looks like Apple's?

Comment: Either I don't understand all the capabilities of CSSs or the differences are a lot more than a CSS can handle. For example, all the stuff in the left-hand column has a completely different structure, not just different look.

I've looked at several examples of using doxygen in addition to my own experiments. Everything I've seen shows doxygen output as having a very distinctive structure, format, and look, which is very different from that delivered by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, the Doxygen output looking and behaving like an Apple Developer Library Document is still to be discovered...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also really interested in this :( Ive been able to generate docsets and doxygen docs but if I could make them look the same (or approaching) as the "normal" apple docs (like SDK ones), that would be better. :/